# Add names to cluster elements

Tags: labview

I am interfacing a LabVIEW VI with an Arduino Leonardo that reads a bunch of sensors and ADCs, collects the data, and then sends the result over the serial port in a single comma delimited sentence. My LabVIEW sub-VI takes the sentence and uses the `Spreadsheet String To Array` function to split it up into a vector of doubles. Since there are currently 20 readings per sentence, I would like to turn the array into a cluster with `Array to Cluster` and pass the cluster out of the sub-VI.

The problem with this approach is that the elements of the cluster are named `[0]`, `[1]`, etc., which is not helpful. Is there a way, short of unbundling and then rebundling, or indexing each array element and then bundling, to add a name to each element?

I'm using LabVIEW 2009.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create your cluster as a constant (preferably a typedef) and typecast the unnamed cluster into the named cluster.
Example:
[image]

EDIT
If your number of cluster and data type match you don't even need the type cast.

Comment: That is exactly what I needed. Just one quick(?) question, though. This is going to run as a compiled binary on a pretty slow, memory limited computer. Between typecasting, unbundling/rebundling, and array indexing/bundling, which will have the best memory and CPU performance?

Comment: Type casting is pretty much free so is the array to cluster.  Make sure your number of elements is correct (right click on the array to cluster function).

Comment: I figured that last one out the hard way a while ago.